# Can I use --duplicate-cn option for a specific VPN account instead of using at server level?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

If I use `--duplicate-cn` I am seeing it taking effect over all the accounts of my server. I want to make it per client basis, so that I can give this option only to select accounts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duplicate-cn` option does apply to the entire server, so in order to do this you will need to run two instances of OpenVPN (and they will have to run on different ports).

If you're using EL7 or Fedora this is very easy to set up. Create `/etc/openvpn/server1.conf` and `/etc/openvpn/server2.conf` with your unique configurations, and then enable them both:

```
systemctl enable openvpn@server1
systemctl enable openvpn@server2
systemctl start openvpn@server1
systemctl start openvpn@server2
```